# cannot deserialize an xml in a bndtools osgi project

Tags: java, xml-serialization, osgi, bndtools

I am fairly new to osgi and bndtools and started with the bndtools [tutorial](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html)

the tutorial worked fine and then i tried to play around with my own test project where i implement an interface , and in the implementation , i am trying to deserialize an xml file to a java class using [org.simpleframework](https://blogs.oracle.com/sreekanth/entry/using_simple_framwork_to_serialiaze)

I get the following classnotfound exception. Also , I did include the package(which the class in question is a part of)  as a part of the private packages in the bundle that i am running

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packagename.classname   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.Loader.load(Loader.java:50)  at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.readValue(TreeStrategy.java:163)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.read(TreeStrategy.java:102)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getOverride(Source.java:370)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getConversion(Factory.java:207)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getOverride(Factory.java:139)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.ObjectFactory.getInstance(ObjectFactory.java:63)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:141)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:687)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:635)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:610)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:593)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:506)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readSection(Composite.java:388)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:367)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:234)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:202)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:150)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.populate(CompositeList.java:175)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.read(CompositeList.java:148)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:682)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:635)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:610)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:593)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:506)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readSection(Composite.java:388)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:367)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readDefault(Composite.java:262)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:232)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:202)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:150)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:687)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:635)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:610)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:593)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:506)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readSection(Composite.java:388)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:367)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readDefault(Composite.java:262)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:232)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:202)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:150)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.populate(CompositeList.java:175)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.read(CompositeList.java:148)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:682)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:635)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:610)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:593)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:506)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readSection(Composite.java:388)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:367)
>     at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readDefault(Composite.java:262)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:232)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:202)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:150)
>     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:632)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:613)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:591)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:550)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:528)   at
>   org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:433)   at
>   com.mlsm.implementation.MLSMImpl.parseMLSM(MLSMImpl.java:150)     at
>   com.mlsm.implementation.MLSMImpl.executeInternal(MLSMImpl.java:84)    at
>   com.mlsm.implementation.MLSMImpl.parseAndExecute(MLSMImpl.java:182)
>     at com.mlsm.implementation.MLSMImpl.start(MLSMImpl.java:65)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.invoke(ServiceImpl.java:484)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.activateService(ServiceImpl.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.access$000(ServiceImpl.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl$3.run(ServiceImpl.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.SerialExecutor.execute(SerialExecutor.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.calculateStateChanges(ServiceImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.ServiceImpl.start(ServiceImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.DependencyManager.add(DependencyManager.java:56)
>     at com.mlsm.implementation.Activator.init(Activator.java:24)    at
>   org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.DependencyActivatorBase.start(DependencyActivatorBase.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2152)
>     at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2070)    at
>   org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)  at
>   aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:422)     at
>   aQute.launcher.Launcher.activate(Launcher.java:346)   at
>   aQute.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:235)    at
>   aQute.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)

This is what in do in service start()

```
public void start() {
      Serializer serializer = new Persister();
      File result = new File(filePath);
      serializer.read(<ClassToSerializeTo>.class, result);
}
```

One more thing to note is that this code works fine outside of the osgi framework. Let me know if more information will help debug the issue.

I also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861342/how-do-you-deserialize-an-object-from-bytes-in-osgi) but am still confused about the issue at hand.

EDIT:
So i found out that this only happens if the xml has an element which looks like this

```
   <TestElement class="PackageName.Classname">
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding these two lines before the deserialization code [Reference](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/classnotfoundexception-when-running-simple-xml/)

ClassLoader thisClassLoader = .getClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(thisClassLoader);

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the current version of the simple-xml.jar. The Manifest shows now OSGi attributes. So my guesss is that this library is not written with OSGi in mind. So it probably has classloading issues. You should ask on their mailing list if they should work on OSGi.

If it is a problem in the framework then the developers can likely fix this. Maybe you can find a workaround but it might not bee easy.